# neo4j client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: java, authentication, neo4j, upgrade

Running Windows 10 Pro. I have been running neo4j 3.5.14 Community because it will run on JRE/JDK 8.  I would like to upgrade to neo4j 4.x, but it needs JDK 11 which does not have JRE.  I am clueless what those words mean, just parroting what I read.  I installed JDK11 anyway, downloaded neo4j 4.2.6 and tried to start it.  It gives this response:

C:\neo4j\neo4j-community-4.2.6\bin>neo4j console
2021-05-14 14:12:23.440+0000 INFO  Starting...

2021-05-14 14:12:25.808+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.2.6 ========

2021-05-14 14:12:26.936+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 2 and status CURRENT

2021-05-14 14:12:26.936+0000 INFO  Updating the initial password in component 'security-users'

2021-05-14 14:12:27.909+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.

2021-05-14 14:12:28.637+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/

2021-05-14 14:12:28.638+0000 INFO  Started.

2021-05-14 14:12:32.067+0000 WARN  The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

I then open a browser

http://localhost:7474/browser/

And it shows a screen with "Connect to Neo4j" with

Connect URL: bolt://localhost:7687

Username neo4j

Password

I tried my existing password, which doesn't work.  I tried the default neo4j as password, and it brings up the "New password" screen.  I enter my password, and it gives this error:

Neo.ClientError.Security.CredentialsExpired: Permission denied. The credentials you provided were valid, but must be changed before you can use this instance. If this is the first time you are using Neo4j, this is to ensure you are not using the default credentials in production. If you are not using default credentials, you are getting this message because an administrator requires a password change. Changing your password is easy to do via the Neo4j Browser. If you are connecting via a shell or programmatically via a driver, just issue a `ALTER CURRENT USER SET PASSWORD FROM 'current password' TO 'new password'`

I stopped the server, restarted as neo4j-community-3.5.14 and it runs.  Stopped that, started 4.2.6, same roadblock.  I cannot get past the "New password" screen.  I have no clue whether this is something to do with JRE, or some other way that I'm completely clueless trying to navigate the cryptic docs.